# How to calculate the maximum safe load on a horizontal wooden beam?

Tags: wood, load-bearing

I am thinking of constructing a wooden bed/desk/roof/shed/ship/bridge/rocket

- How can I calculate the maximum load a rectangular horizontal wooden beam of dimensions L x H x W can safely support if the beam is adequately supported at both ends?

  - assuming worst case - load concentrated at center
  - for commonly available types of wood (e.g. Spruce)

Comment: Damnit, now I want to build a bed/desk/roof/shed/ship/bridge/rocket.

Answer (score 9):

There are lots of span calculators available online, which help you determine what size lumber to use in home or deck construction.  For example

http://www.awc.org/codes-standards/calculators-software/reversecalc

and

http://www.awc.org/codes-standards/calculators-software/spancalc

You could try to figure out what the live loads and dead loads for the bed are and go from there.

Shortcut - I might try to get by with 2x4's spaced 2' or less apart if they run side to side across a single mattress,  but I'd want 2x6's if they run long ways, or for a full or larger.

Comment: Great resources!

Comment: These are excellent resources (+1) for *uniformly loaded beams*, especially for floors and roofs. I am waiting to see if anyone also finds something for loads concentrated at a point.

Comment: reverse-calc link is broken

Answer (score 5):

Your question referred to a simple central load.  So the formula here seems useful:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexural_strength

Looking up the bending strength of Spruce here:

http://workshopcompanion.com/KnowHow/Design/Nature_of_Wood/3_Wood_Strength/3_Wood_Strength.htm

We get 10,200 psi.

Assuming a 6ft length of 4x4 that actually measures 3.5 inches square, and plugging these numbers into the formula, we get:

10,200 psi * (2 * 3.5in * 3.5in^2) / (3 * 72in) = 4049.306 pounds

This appears to be the point at which your beam will deform.

Comment: @ LRU I think you’ve calculated the load at which point the beam will “yield” or “fail” in bending. You need to factor a “safety factor” into your calculations. I use working stress, not ultimate strength.  Usually shear governs for short spans, and bending governs on longer spans. I get about 1,000 lbs. (not 4,000 lbs.) before horizontal shear failure.

Comment: any references in metric system?

Answer (score 3):

Here are two documents I've found helpful, giving specs for southern yellow pine, which is the wood typically used in treated lumber for its added strength compared to SPF pines.

- http://www.southernpine.com/app/uploads/SS_7-12L.pdf
- http://www.southernpine.com/app/uploads/SS_13-14L.pdf

Comment: These documents are for uniformly loaded lumber in a repetitive installation. Op is seeking “maximum load”.