# Can a 6x6 post be used horizontally to support the walls of a shed?

Tags: construction

Can a 6x6 post be used horizontally to support exterior walls of a shed?  6 x 6 will be supported every 5 ft on a concrete pier.

Comment: Can it? Sure! Should it for yours? No idea! How big is the shed? What's it made out of? What kind of roofing? What kind of loads are you putting in it? [Edit] your post to provide as much detail (without going into a long story) as possible. BTW - if the 6x6 has its long direction horizontally, it's called a "beam", when it's standing on its 6x6 end, then it's called a "post". Using the right terms helps eliminate confusion. It's OK, we all gotta start somewhere!

Comment: As long as it is a regular type backyard/garden type it should be okay.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate the maximum safe load on a horizontal wooden beam?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/76153/how-to-calculate-the-maximum-safe-load-on-a-horizontal-wooden-beam)

Answer (score 2):

Almost absolutely. A 5' span is small enough that there's almost no shed you could build that wouldn't be fine on those timbers. It's only if you're talking 20' walls and a huge roof span that I'd be concerned.

If you want a more confident answer, tell us more about your shed. Size, wall sheathing, floor framing, and other factors are relevant.

Note that they should really be pressure-treated or isolated from the concrete and protected from ground moisture (splash).

Comment: +1 for recommending protection from ground, concrete, etc.

Comment: Also, please note location relative to seismic and wind loads.